# Elasticsearch Best Practices Flow

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic-search for product filtering for products. We have complex logic of product availability. I can see two options

Using elastic to store only product specific data and product availability logic resides in web server part. we first filter data from elastic then check the condition on those result set if it matches the logic of availability.

or We can flatten the data and store it in elastic though for that case there will be duplicates of data.

My concern is if it is good practice to call elastic endpoint from browser. As it does not have any auth system by default. and every query and response will be visible in network log. I believe call should be made from web server to elastic and front end will communicate with elastic unaware of elastic existence.

Any best practice insight will be helpful

Comment: Well expose the data directly from browser is usually not a good idea and should be dodge if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create and authenticated endpoint in your backend and send the queries to that endpoint. Do make sure there are some enforced limits such as

- `size` -- You don't want to let anybody download your whole index and
- `aggregation` depth -- you don't want anyone to perform summaries on your whole index/indices to get a competitive advantage.

Regarding the duplicates: I wouldn't worry too much about the storage aspect (many NoSQL approaches will probably have some duplication to facilitate fast queries) but keep in mind that aggregations might yield "wrong" counts and sums. You'd typically perform those aggregations to get, say, the totals in your product categories and you want to make sure they are representative of your warehouse state.

More cannot really be said right now based on the limited information you've provided.